# Bizarre Rails4 error when using link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, error-handling

This line of code:

```
<%=link_to('Click for video.', image_path("create_institution.gif"), :target => "_blank")%>
```

Is throwing this error:

```
Couldn't find Image with 'id'=create_institution

Request parameters  
{"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"images", "id"=>"create_institution", "format"=>"gif"}
```

Is this a problem with my routes or something else?  `"create_institution.gif"` is in `/assets/images`  I have a model "Images" but have not had a problem using images elsewhere.

Pastebin of [my routes.rb](http://pastebin.com/RU7nnvL8)

Comment: Thanks Arun.  Am trying to display a text anchor that, when clicked , opens a window that plays a gif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application, you have `image` as a resource and that is why `image_path` resolves to `images#show`

From the documentation of `image_path`,

> If you have images as application resources this method may conflict with their named routes. The alias path_to_image is provided to avoid that. Rails uses the alias internally, and plugin authors are encouraged to do so.

So, you can use `path_to_image` to resolve this.

```
<%=link_to('Click for video.', path_to_image("create_institution.gif"), :target => "_blank")%>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That works.  I see the explanation here now: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_path  Hmmm... perhaps Rails should lose the 'image_path' option?

Comment: SO is making me wait 2 more minutes to give you the credit you deserve.